# Making iframe work with variable in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I have created a custom meta field and I would like to save an iframe link on my posts.

When I retrieve the link from my meta field with the code below:

```
echo soundcloud_get_meta( 'soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode' );
```

I get the whole iframe as a text!

But when I give the link as in the code below it works

```
echo '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/151456970&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
```

I think it puts extra quotes on the first example and  get as a text. 
How can I make this work with the first example?

**UPDATE**

this is in my functions.php file

```
function soundcloud_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'soundcloud-soundcloud',
        __( 'SoundCloud', 'soundcloud' ),
        'soundcloud_html',
        'post',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'soundcloud_add_meta_box' );

function soundcloud_html( $post) {
    wp_nonce_field( '_soundcloud_nonce', 'soundcloud_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>SoundCloud</p>

    <p>
        <label for="soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode"><?php _e( 'SoundCloud Shortcode', 'soundcloud' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode" id="soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode" value="<?php echo soundcloud_get_meta( 'soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode' ); ?>">
    </p><?php
}

function soundcloud_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['soundcloud_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['soundcloud_nonce'], '_soundcloud_nonce' ) ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode', esc_attr( $_POST['soundcloud_soundcloud_shortcode'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'soundcloud_save' );
```

Comment: Can you update with whole code of your function?

Comment: the code added from my functions.php

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `html_entity_decode` on my function to output as html